# Best way to resolve conflict from two @types in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Okay imagine I have a typescript project, and I do

`npm install --save-dev @types\libA`

This libA declares a new type, lets call it,

```
interface Something {
    market: any;
}
```

Then I do

`npm install --save-dev @types\libB`

And this decides to redefine Something to

```
interface Something {
    market: Market
}
interface Market {
    // strongly typed definition
}
```

These two libraries are out of my control, I am not the author.
But I am presented with an error message, during compilation,

`error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.`

Questions:

1. As a consumer of libA and libB, what is the best way for me to resolve this conflict?
2. As a library author, if I wish to extend an existing interface, but keep the same name, what is the best way?

Thanks!

Comment: You can avoid naming conflicts by using modules or namespaces

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?